# How to load data series saved in an excel cell into a numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a time series saved in an excel cell, which I want to load for future calculations. I have tried to load them using pandas, but get something like this

```
KE = '[ 0.  0.  0. ... nan nan nan]'
```

KE.type is giving this response -

> 'numpy.str_' object has no attribute 'type'

I want KE to be a time series as I saved the array to the cell, which should be like this

```
KE = [0,0,0,.......nan,nan,nan]
```

Could you guys please help me here, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is string, following should help you ...

```
KE = '[0. 0. 0. nan nan]'.replace('[','').replace(']','').split(' ')
print(np.array(list(map(float,KE))))

#op
array([ 0.,  0.,  0., nan, nan])
```